# BLU phone having trouble downloading apps

Tags: google-play-store, sd-card, insufficient-memory, storage

I have a BLU Advance 5.0 and a 64 GB SD card already in it. I changed preferred install location to the SD Card and I also change the default write disk to the SD card. But after every download from Google Play Store, I have to manually put each app onto the SD Card. And now, even though I have every app on the SD Card and have everything set to the SD card, the phone still tries to download every app onto the internal storage, that is still saying "insufficient storage". What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

called the company of Blu. they will be sending a new update that will fix app problem. They were aware of the problem.